# Screen share/Apple Remote Desktop/other severely slows down the Mac Pro (3,1) being shared

Tags: performance, remote-desktop, mac-pro, gpu

All I wanna do is run a headless Mac Pro(3,1, with DosDudes patch for Mojave). The instant I connect, mouse/keyboard latency becomes intolerably slow, on the Mac Pro itself, whether I'm looking at it through the two MacBooks I tried this with, or sitting in front of the Mac Pro). WindowServer spikes to over 50% just sitting there in Activity Monitor, on the target Mac Pro. If I move a window around, it exceeds 100%.

And not just Screen Sharing and Apple Remote Desktop; I get this using ConnectWise Control Client also (it's kinda like TeamViewer).  As soon as I disconnect, latency vanishes on the Mac Pro and I can wave a window around smoothly and fast.

Info follows, and after that a list of things-I-tried.  I'll update with more troubleshooting.

To be clear, I'm testing with a monitor attached.  The problem persists on the remote end when monitor is unplugged.

*MacPro3,1 ("Mac Pro (Early 2008)")*
*2 * 2.8 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon  (8 cores total)*

*Memory:    16 GB*

*Boot ROM Version:    MP31.006C.B05*
*SMC Version (system):    1.25f4*

*NVIDIA GeForce GT 120  512MB*
*running 1920 x 1080  24-Bit Color*

*Mojave macOS 10.14.6 (18G9323) via DosDude patch.**

**Things I tried/notes.**

With 800*600 rez (unacceptably small) the problem isn't as bad.
Several restarts, reset SMC and nvram, force-quit WindowServer, turned off firewall and little snitch, direct Ethernet connection via Cat5e bypassing router, trashed all Google services and apps, turned off all accessibility features; turned off "Displays have separate spaces" and logged out and back in.  Will next try different OS.

Comment: As I have a similar Pro 3,1 [still on El Cap] with no issue like that at all… I'd take a good guess at it being Mojave, which needs Metal2 graphics. It's bad enough even on a 4,1 or 5,1 without a good GPU. The standard Apple HD5770 doesn't cut it, a GT120 is going to be hopeless. You really need an HD7950 or better for Mojave. Try it back on an un-hacked El Cap, see how it compares.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for this.  It worked fine under Sierra, so I think it would also in El Cap (unless a hardware problem coincidentally happened while I updated to Mojave).  To be clear, under Mojave, the video is just fine...until I connect via ARD, screen sharing, or ConnectWise Control Client. Then latency instantly becomes really bad.  Dosdude1's mod specifically does support pre-Metal video cards.  But yeah, I still suspect the card is affecting screen-sharing performance, and think I'll try a better card.

Comment: Wish you luck. I have no direct comparison, but the two newer Pros here, a franken-mac firmware tweaked 4,1 with uprated 3.46GHz Westmere Xeons &  'true' 5,1 both have the 7950 cards in & behave just fine on what are now technically 'legit' Mojave installs, no dosdude required. The 3,1 with 5770 I did some experimenting but dropped it back to El Cap. All are fine on ARD, & that's about the only way I contact them these days.